# How can swap through Raydium using Python

Tags: python, swap

Please, I need help.

How can swap through Raydium using Python?

If I have, for example:

Token Address = '8wXtPeU6557ETkp9WHFY1n1EcU6NxDvbAggHGsMYiHsB' # I want buy

Wallet Key = 'asuhduiahsw812y98dajsdui172yashduiahsuidh11sjhdahduiashduh1892hdhsuahdh199d89hashANDSO1ON'

My Sol Address = 'uR8r9X23uB5F9kSHGFN77vaE8HSwzEykZovmgcvFaR5'

Amount In Sol = '0.2' Sol #Amount To Buy In Sol

What the code of python I can use for swap in Raydium?
Also,
where do I put the above data in the code of python?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Bassam.

I search and I don't find.

Comment: Welcome to SO :) I don't know anything about Sol, but I suspect you probably don't want to be posting your token/key in a public forum?